# angular js: Prevent Bootstrap Modal from disappearing when clicking outside or pressing escape?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

Am using the angular bootstrap to present a modal. But my requirement is to prevent pop-up dismissal when clicking outside the modal, or when the escape key is pressed.

I followed the tutorial on the angular bootstrap site :http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

[image]

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Use:

```
backdrop: 'static'
```

> `backdrop` - controls presence of a backdrop. Allowed values: true
>   (default), false (no backdrop), 'static' - backdrop is present but
>   modal window is not closed when clicking outside of the modal window.

For example:

```
$modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      backdrop: 'static'
    })
```

Comment: Works without a doubt as the answer below confirms

Answer (score 46):

Add both `backdrop: static` and `keyboard: false` to your modal options. The first one disables the background click, the second one the escape key.

> `backdrop: 'static'` - backdrop is present but modal window is not closed when clicking outside of the modal window.
>
> `keyboard` - indicates whether the dialog should be closable by hitting the ESC key, defaults to true.

Example:

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  controller: TheController,
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false
})
```

[See the docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for more information.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it resolves both of the requirements as outlined by the OP.

Comment: As said, the best and more broad answer

Answer (score 10):

"**backdrop** - controls presence of a backdrop. Allowed values: true (default), false (no backdrop), 'static' - backdrop is present but modal window is not closed when clicking outside of the modal window." - in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Try:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl" data-backdrop="static">
...
</div>
```